# MySql and RDS Connection

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I created a MySQL instance in RDS. Successfully connected in MySQL Workbench. But when I want to connect it with my asp.net core application with following connection-string, it gives error on opening the connection:

> "DefaultConnection": "Server=zargham.ccir1327bjhl.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com; Port=3306;Database=aws; Uid=[username]; Pwd=[password];"

*Although connection is successful in the application when I connect to a local db instance.

Comment: It may be that remote pc disallows port 3306 to go outside.

Comment: But it shouldn't be connected on MySql workbench. It connects successfully on MYsql workbench.